# Jungle Fortitude damage reduction not appearing on Details window

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-witch-doctor

The witch doctor passive skill [Jungle Fortitude](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/witch-doctor/passive/jungle-fortitude) reduced damage taken by 15%.

However, when this skill is selected, the "Damage Reduction" value on the "Details" information window does not increase. Is it possible that this skill does nothing?

Comment: jungle fortitude is a WD skill....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The damage reduction field you see in the character details is from armor only.  Not even resistances will affect that %.

The 15% reduction can be considered a separate multiplier from your armor reduction.

I.e. if you have 50% damage reduction from armor, you will take 50 damage from a 100 damage attack.  If you have jungle fortitude as well, you'll take 42.5 damage instead (100*.5*.85).